# How to initialise BaseModel in BaseController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, dependency-injection, model

I have a class of properties which are set from a service which I need available on every view of my MVC application.

Therefore I've created a "Base View Model" which my view models will inherit from.

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
        foo = "foo value";
        bar = "bar value";
    }

    public string foo { get; set; }

    public string bar { get; set; }
}

public class HomeIndexViewModel : BaseModel
{
}
```

I have then created a "Base Controller" which all my controllers will inherit from:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeIndexViewModel model = new HomeIndexViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This is working as expected and I can call `@Model.foo` in my view and get `foo value`.

However I don't believe I should be initialising the values of `BaseModel` in it's constructor as this isn't using Dependency Injection and will become difficult to unit test.

**How can I move the setting of the values `foo` and `bar` into the `BaseController`?**

Of course I could set the values in the `HomeController`, but I would rather abstract this from the controller as the logic will always be the same and would bloat all my controllers.

Comment: @nopeflow Can you please provide an example of what you mean? Thanks

Comment: @Curl I have deleted my comment, I think that I misunderstood the question, now I see that my comment had no sense.

Comment: Don't you want to pass this params to `BaseController` Constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating the instance of your models inside of the *action*, so the base controller has no reference to the object to set the properties.

Personally I would probably opt for some 'factory-type' function in the base controller that is responsible for creating the models as you need them.

Something like this for example:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public T CreateBaseModel<T>() where T : BaseModel, new()
    {
        return new T
        {
            foo = "foo value",
            bar = "bar value"
        };
    }
}
```

Then when you create your models in the actions you can do them like this:

```
HomeIndexViewModel model = CreateBaseModel<HomeIndexViewModel>();
```

---

If for some reason you need to pass parameters to your model constructor then you can have an overload like this:

```
public T CreateBaseModel<T>(params object[] args) where T : BaseModel
{
    T model = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    model.foo = "foo";
    return model;
}

HomeIndexViewModel model = CreateBaseModel<HomeIndexViewModel>(param1, param2, etc);
```

---

**Alternative**

The main benefit of the above method is that you can access the `foo` and `bar` properties within the action code. However, if you don't care about this and only need the values to be accessible from within the View page, then you can override the `OnActionExecuted` method and apply the values in there. The benefit of this approach is that you don't need to change the way your models are created in the actions...

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    BaseModel model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as BaseModel;
    if (model != null)
    {
        model.foo = "foo value";
        model.bar = "bar value";
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Having the `null` check in there means it will only try to apply the values for models that inherit from `BaseModel`, which means you can still use other models without worry.

With this approach, your action code goes back to how it was originally:

```
HomeIndexViewModel model = new HomeIndexViewModel();
return View(model);
```

Comment: `OnActionExecuted` did the trick!! Thanks - a million kudos to you sir

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for the edit, didn't know about that but looks good!